# After sending text to ckeditor it does not recognize next element (selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, ckeditor

i successfully send text to `ckeditor` through these command

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement tinymce = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
tinymce.clear();
tinymce.sendKeys("Automation Description");
```

**Problem**

Text "Automation Description" is succesfully passed to `ckeditor`. 
But. it does not locate the next element
Following error is displayed

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='select2-state_name-container']"}

When I added Block Comment to

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement tinymce = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
tinymce.clear();
tinymce.sendKeys("Automation Description");
```

It successful located the next element.

Help me to add a command so that I can locate next element after texting text to ckeditor. Thank you

---

Here's a screen shot:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: what did you add as in "When I added Block Comment to"?

Comment: which element is the "next element"? I went to ckeditor HTML, there is no "select2-state_name-container" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I seeing your code you are going to switch frame first then find ckeditor and set value. But you didn't switch back to default content to find the next element that's why selenium searching the locator into already switched frame where element is not present actually, So you should try to switch back before finding element as below :-

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement tinymce = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
tinymce.clear();
tinymce.sendKeys("Automation Description");

//Now switch back first to default 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

 //Now you can go to find next element
```

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with your switch frame statement,

```
driver.switchTo().frame()
```

Try to switch back to 0 index frame or default one after inputting the text:

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement tinymce = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
tinymce.clear();
tinymce.sendKeys("Automation Description");
driver.switchTo().frame(0); //To go back to main frame
//continue
```

Or better yet find the selector for the main frame window and swicth to it, but i think 0 should work in your case

Hope this helps

Comment: driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

with this command its working